# iOS Collection View with Pinch zoom on each cell

Tags: ios, ios4, ios6

I am using a collection view with a bunch of Images. I would like to add the capability to pinch zoom on each item in the collection view. Not sure what's the best way to implement this? I appreciate any help.

I want to be able to use pinch to zoom in the following items 
http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Screen-Shot-2012-09-23-at-1.59.29-PM.png

Thanks, 
Faz

Answer (score 0):

Basically you add a `UIScrollView` to each of your collection views. Then you add the `UIImageViews` for your images as subviews of the scrollviews. The scrollview supports "pinch-zooming" out of the box.

See this tutorial:[How To Use UIScrollView to Scroll and Zoom Content](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content), for info on how to setup a scrollview for zooming.